# Quel genre grammatical pour les personnes transgenres ?

Tags: genre

Dans un article Wikipedia sur deux garçons transexuels ceux-ci sont identifiés par le genre grammatical féminin dans l'intégralité de l'article. Par exemple :

> X et Y sont deux réalisatrices américaines

Quel est la règle ? Est-ce qu'on utilise le genre de transition rétroactivement ? A partir du moment de transition ? Ou pas du tout ?

Answer (score 4):

Le nouveau genre est pris en compte à partir de la transition.

Pour ce qui concerne la période antérieure, tout dépend de la référence.

Si c'est la personne actuelle, on peut garder le nouveau genre, mais si l'on parle de la personne telle qu'elle était auparavant, par exemple un utilisant son ancien prénom, le genre antérieur sera utilisé.

Comment: Entendu. Avez-vous des références ?

Comment: Non, pas de référence particulières. Je ne sais pas s'il y a des règles officielles et si c'est le cas, j'imagine que le changement de genre doit être pris en compte lorsque l'état-civil est modifié plutôt que lors de la transition physique. Ma réponse s'appuie plutôt sur l'observation de l'usage.

Comment: On préfère parfois une révision même des anciennes références

Answer (score 0):

On utilise bien le genre d'après la transition.

Je ne sais pas si c'est ce que tu as voulu dire, mais quand tu dis "un garçon transgenre", c'est une personne qui était identifiée comme une fille et qui l'est maintenant comme un garçon. À partir du moment où c'est un garçon, c'est logique d'utiliser le masculin, non ?

Donc par exemple, pour une femme transgenre (au hasard, les sœurs Wachowski), on utilise naturellement le féminin.